# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Touchpad Edge Scrolling setting won't stay on. Turns off on its own right after I enable it

Tags: touchpad

Super Ubuntu noob here. So please be gentle. I just downloaded ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my old Dell Inspiron laptop. Touchpad Edge scrolling turns off shortly after I turn it on. Everytime I restart/shut down, or go into the touchpad settings menu, I need to re-enable edge-scrolling. Anybody know why it keeps turning off on it's own, or how to make it stay on?

Thanks

Comment: In touchpad settings, try manually turning off "two finger scrolling" and then flip on "edge scrolling" and see if that sticks.

Comment: There is no "two finger scrolling" option in my touchpad settings. The only settings, are "natural scrolling", "touchpad speed", "tap to click" and "edge scrolling".

Comment: There may be a hidden setting that's specific to your account. Log into another account, create one temporarily if you have to, and see if you can enable edge scrolling there. Report back. Then I can give you the next step, depending on the results.

Comment: Had to restart for an unrelated resason. Wasn't able to try what you suggested because now screen freezes as soon as I log-on. No idea wtf is going on. Re-installing a fresh copy of 20.04 now. Will get back to you once I can actually log on...

Comment: The edge scrolling problem and the current screen freezing problem, are probably related. I wish you could have contacted me first, before re-installing. Report back when you can.

Comment: I see. My bad. Anyway, I tried adding another user, enabling edge scrolling. It works with both users, but as soon as I click on another setting or click out of the settings window, it reverts the edge scrolling setting back to the "off" position. Edge scrolling works until my laptop sleeps or restarts, or until I go into settings for anything, at which point I need to re-enable it.

Comment: Did edge scrolling work the same way in the other user account? The sleep/restart clue should be in your question. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me your exact make/model # computer.

Comment: Yed Edge scrolling works the same on both user accounts. Works fine until I go into touchpad settings or if I shut down/restart. Everytime I go to touchpad setting menu, it's disabled, and I have to re-enable it.

Comment: All thats shown when i enter what you said is "A01". Im using a 2009 Dell Inspiron 1764 laptop.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon that's just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I've downloaded the bios update driver file. Can I go into boot menu and boot from the usb stick it's on, or is it a whole lot more complicated, do I need to use a 3rd party app such as freeDOS and UNetbootin?

Comment: There's two different download files available. One requires something like a freeDOS bootable USB flash, and the other can be done from Windows. Installation instructions can be found at the bottom of the download page.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command in terminal to check if "two finger scrolling" is enabled.
`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad two-finger-scrolling-enabled`
If the output is `true` then you should disable "two finger scrolling" by running: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad two-finger-scrolling-enabled false`. Then try enabling "edge scrolling".

Answer (score 0):

You have BIOS A01.

There's a newer BIOS, A13, that may resolve your problem, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=r301041&oscode=biosa&productcode=inspiron-1764)

There's two different download files available. One requires something like a freeDOS bootable USB flash, and the other can be done from Windows. Installation instructions can be found at the bottom of the download page.